# Calculus derivation of OLS regression formula

Tags: regression, least-squares

Edited to make the question more clear.

In deriving the OLS formula from calculus, that is, solving 
$$\min_{\beta}(Y-X\beta)^T(Y-X\beta).$$
How could be guarantee the solution is actually the minimum? I read something like "because $X$ is full-rank, so $X^TX$ is positive definite". Could anyone show me how to conclude that $X^TX$ is positive definite out of $X$ is full-rank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ is $n \times k$ where $k\le n$. So $X$ full rank means the rank of $X$ is $k$. Now if $x$ is $k \times 1$, then $y=Xx$ is *definite*: $Xx=0$ iff $x=0$ by the full rank of $X$ (if not, some $k \times 1$ basis vector $e$ would have $Xe=0$, contradicting full rank). Finally, $x^TX^TXx=y^Ty$ is clearly *positive*, and so $X^TX$ is positive-definite.

Comment: @Severus: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks very much. That is exactly what I want to ask.

Comment: @Severus: Great! Could you consider selecting my answer as correct?

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: @Severus: Just click the check mark (√) next to my answer!

Comment: Done. I am kind of new here. Also, I just post a new question about constrained least square. Maybe you can help me out of that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the definition of positive definite matrix. You will find that the objective function is convex. And the second order derivative with respect to $\beta$ is $X^TX$. When it is positive definite, like $y=f(x)$, if at $x^{\ast}$ the second derivative is positive, $f(x)$ achieve its minimum.

Comment: Thanks. But that is not what I try to ask. The question is: why $X^TX$ is positive definite given $X$ is full rank.

Comment: OK, think like this: for any vector $v$, $v^TX^TXv=(Xv)^T(Xv)=a^Ta$, if you think $a=Xv$. Which is always $\geq 0$ for any nonzero vector $v$. If $X$ is full rank, then $X^TX$ is also full rank. $a=Xv\neq 0$ for any nonzero vector $v$. so $v^TX^TXv=(Xv)^T(Xv)>0$. According to the definition of positive definite matrix, $X^TX$ is positive definite.